# What should we do if the OP tries to deny an answer from certain users?

Tags: discussion, guidelines

The policy of Stack Exchange sites is **anybody can ask a question** and **anybody can answer**. This is displayed when someone joins a community.

Now, *what* should we do if the OP of the question asks certain user(s) not to post an answer (because he/she already know the opinions of the user or in the worst case due to opinion clashes)?

For example, they added a note at the end of the question like this:

> Dear X, I have seen your opinions many times regarding this topic and I know what you will say. I suggest you not to answer this.

How should we handle situation like this one?

---

<sup>This is what I have seen from a user on one of the  sites I participate on and such a note is removed by the OP after being asked to do so.</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We're interested in the content, not in the person.

Explicitly asking a specific user to not answer is likely to be counterproductive. It is also likely to cause heated emotions and pointless drama.
As PolyGeo points out in [their answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294987/168333), a request like that is irrelevant to the question, and will be edited out. Similarly, asking a user not to contribute in a comment, will just result in the comment getting flagged and removed.

The closest thing you could do, is create a userscript that hides the contributions of a particular user. Or just ignore that user.

Note that you can vote, but you should vote on the contents - if their anwer is factually wrong, by all means downvote. But if their answer is factually correct, and you just don't like it - that's not a reason to downvote.

Answer (score 5):

No, but if you think their question is not useful then you are free to downvote it, if you have achieved the privilege to do so.

Also, I would expect a comment like that to be perceived as chit chat and edited out of your question.