# How binding are Meta answers?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, community-standards

I recently had a user on a particular StackExchange site direct me to a Meta answer in a case that was not specifically addressed elsewhere in the site guidelines.

It turned out that the answer linked was from the same person directing me to it.  The answer had 4 votes and was the only answer to the question relating to the issue I raised. This particular user stated that his answer represented "the consensus on Meta".

This occurred on the Christianity SE and the Meta was the Christianity Meta.  The answer that contained the comment with a link was deleted by a moderator and I haven't been able to locate the Meta question and answer since.  But it related to what sort of answers would be and would not be acceptable for questions asking about the "Biblical basis" for something.  I disagree with the singleton Meta answer and am trying to determine to what extent that particular answer is or is not binding on Christianity SE users.  But I am also keenly interested in the general case as well.

My questions:

1. Can Meta answers be considered binding on users?
2. If so, what constitutes a binding vs. a non-binding answer?   For example, is only the most highly voted answer considered binding?  Would a solo answer with just one vote be considered binding? 2 votes? 4 votes?   Does it make any difference if the Meta answer is accepted?

Comment: A meta answer on the child meta or on main meta? Can we get some more details? What was the question?

Comment: @Catija - I edited my question to provide more info.  Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Abochur not really a dupe at all. This is not about "highly upvoted" answers... four upvotes really isn't "highly upvoted".

Comment: @Abochur - It does relate, but what does "highly upvoted" mean?  I guess my question is slightly different, since it is asking about an answer that was the only one given and that wouldn't (I think) be considered to have been highly upvoted?

Answer (score 6):

To me a rule is binding whereas a guideline is not, and Stack Exchange Q&A operates mostly on guidelines. Consequently, I think this is a duplicate of [Are highly upvoted answers, accepted answers posted here considered as rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305911)

Consensus is hard to measure. On tiny sites one answer with one upvote and no one indicating dissent in answers, votes or comments months after posting might suggest consensus has been reached. The community of each site should decide what they consider represents their consensus. At GIS I usually think an answer 5 higher than any others, even if reached quickly, suggests consensus, but may be overturned by later voting.

Acceptance is only one persons view, which is that of the question asker, who most likely has already voted on one or more answers.  I think it should provide no additional weight to the voting.